# When to use getActivity in addSnapshotListener?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

When to use `getActivity` and `this` or `Executor` in addSnapshotListener .
I read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) and still not clearly understand.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an Activity instance if you want to automatically remove the listener when the activity stops.

Pass an Executor if you want the callback to your listener to happen on a thread other than the main thread.

If you remove the listener yourself, and you want to handle the callback on the main thread, then don't pass anything extra.

Comment: is listener remain remove automatically if i don't use those contexts ? and what happen when i don't put those contexts beside remove ?

Comment: Listeners are never removed automatically if you don't provide an activity. You might leak the listener if you don't remove it.